# Могут ли слова "копытить" и "скопытить" сообщить о некоторой прибыли?

Tags: значение-слов

Неоднократно встречал слово "копытить" в значении "зарабатывать", "скопытить" - в значении "заработать". Но в словарях, в национальном корпусе это слово не связывается с заработками, а с лошадью, повредившей бабку или повалившей кого-что-нибудь. Всего-то несколько примеров в Google-книгах повстречал в этом смысле.

Могут ли эти слова употребляться в приведенном значении (предрекаю, что в этом случае они являются жаргонизмами), доводилось ли вам слышать эти слова в указанных значениях? "Копытить" - копаться в земле - может означать и "искать что-то, находить ценное, полезное" и в этом смысле отождествляться с заработками.

Answer (score 1):

Это из серии "Когда я употребляю какое-нибудь слово", — сказал Шалтай-Болтай довольно презрительно, — "оно означает только то, что я хочу, чтобы оно обозначало, - ни больше, ни меньше"?! Ну как можно слово "наделить значением", которого у него нету?